# How do I use jquery to show classes derived from variables?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to utilize my elements' values in order to make certain classes appear in css, however, it doesn't work. Could you please help? That code worked with option elements. Please check the fiddle below:
https://jsfiddle.net/w99vunx6/

```
    $( "#zero" ).click(function() {
    var $target = $('.c' + $(this).val());
    $target.show();
});

$( "zeroa" ).click(function() {
    var $target = $('.cc' + $(this).val());
    $target.show();
});
```

Comment: `<p>`'s dont have a `value` - use `.text()` - and you're missing the ID selector in front of `zeroa`

Comment: He wants to use the value attribute, though.

Comment: using .text() won't solve the problem, apparently.

Comment: No, `.text()` just gets the text content between the `<p>` and `</p>`. I provided an answer that will work. I updated your jsfiddle so you could test it(link in answer)

Comment: change to `.attr('value')` ... `val()` only works on form control elements. Best to use `data-` attributes though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hugo, a solution you could use for this would be to change the `value` attribute to a data attribute and access it with `$(this).data('value')` instead. Like this:

```
$( "#zero" ).click(function() {
    var $target = $('.c' + $(this).data('value'));
    $target.show();
});

<p id="zero" data-value="0" style="display: inline;">Zero</p>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w99vunx6/1/

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your comment. Didn't know could use data-value in that case, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are assigning a [value](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_value.asp) attribute to a `<p>` paragraph tag.

The value attribute can only be assigned to the following elements: 
`<button>`, `<input>`, `<li>`, `<option>`, `<progress>`, `<param>`

Try targeting the `id`s on the paragraph tags instead like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#zero").click(function() {
    var $target = $('.c' + this.id);
    $target.show();
  });
  $("#zeroa").click(function() {
    var $target = $('.cc' + this.id);
    $target.show();
  });
});
```

```css
.czero {
  display: none;
}

.cczeroa {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="labels">
  <p id="zero" style="display: inline;">Zero</p>
  <p id="zeroa" class="czero">Zero a</p>
  <p id="zeroazero" class="cczeroa">Zero a Zero</p>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dankreiger/w99vunx6/6/)**.